# jQuery dynamic div on the fly with a href

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to create a dynamic div and inserting it over an image.
Everything is working great.  I am also get the source from a hidden div, how can I put the source inside the `<a href` that I am creating with my dynamic div?

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tsource = $('#thesource').val();                           
    $(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after("<div style='width:650px; height:30px; float: left; top:0; position: absolute; margin-top:10px;'><div style='height:23px; padding-top:6px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; background-color:#000; opacity:0.7; color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>Πηγή: <a href='tsource' style='color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>MyLink</a></div></div>");

});
```

And the body:

```
<div class="gdl-blog-full" style="width:650px; height:390px;">
    <img src="4114feed_L.jpg" alt="4114ed_L" width="650" height="390" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-8519">
    <input type="hidden" id="thesource" name="thesource" value="google.com" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to use the value of variable `tsource`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tsource = $('#thesource').val();
    $(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after("<div style='width:650px; height:30px; float: left; top:0; position: absolute; margin-top:10px;'><div style='height:23px; padding-top:6px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; background-color:#000; opacity:0.7; color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>Πηγή: <a href='" + tsource + "' style='color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>MyLink</a></div></div>");

});
```

visual  difference :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

String concatenation:

```
<a href='" + tsource + "'
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, using string concatenation you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var tsource = $('#thesource').val();
   var div_str = "<div style='width:650px; height:30px; float: left; top:0; position:        absolute; margin-top:10px;'><div style='height:23px; padding-top:6px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; background-color:#000; opacity:0.7; color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>Πηγή: <a href='" + tsource + "' style='color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>MyLink</a></div></div>";
   $(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after(div_str );
});
```

Also if you want to add dynamic html, you can use Underscore js using template you able to insert html by passing parameters to that template.